# Registrar valor de un ZXingsacanner en Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, scanner

Lo que pasa es que quiero insertar obteniendo ciertos valores en mi BD Firebase pero al momento de que obtengo el valor de un codigo de barras escaneado mediante camara, el boton registrar se deshabilita y no me deja, pero si lo agrego manualmente si puedo registrar el producto

Este es mi Layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nuevo"
        android:text="Nuevo Producto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtCodigoP"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="@color/negro"
        android:hint="Ingresa el codigo del producto"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEscaner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Escanear" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtNombreP"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="@color/negro"
        android:hint="Ingresa el nombre del producto"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtDescripcionP"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/negro"
            android:hint="Ingresa la descripcion del producto"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPrecioP"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@color/negro"
        android:hint="Precio compra"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPrecio1P"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@color/negro"
        android:hint="Precio venta1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPrecio2P"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@color/negro"
        android:hint="Precio venta2"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPrecio3P"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@color/negro"
        android:hint="Precio venta3"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtCantidadP"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@color/negro"
        android:hint="Cantidad"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtFechaP"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:textColor="@color/negro"
        android:hint="Fecha de Compra"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnIngresar"
        android:text="Registrar"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#2E64FE"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Este es mi Clase

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevo_producto);

    //edtCodigoP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtCodigoP);
    edtNombreP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNombreP);
    edtDescripcionP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtDescripcionP);
    edtPrecioP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrecioP);
    edtPrecio1P = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrecio1P);
    edtPrecio2P = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrecio2P);
    edtPrecio3P = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrecio3P);
    edtCantidadP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCantidadP);
    edtFechaP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtFechaP);

    btnIngresar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIngresar);

    btnEscanear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEscaner);
    btnEscanear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Escanear(view);
        }
    });

    //final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    //final DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Productos");
    final DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Productos");
    btnIngresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NuevosProd prod = new NuevosProd(edtCodigoP.getText().toString(),edtNombreP.getText().toString(),
                    edtDescripcionP.getText().toString(), edtPrecioP.getText().toString(),edtPrecio1P.getText().toString(),
                    edtPrecio2P.getText().toString(),edtPrecio3P.getText().toString(),edtCantidadP.getText().toString(),
                    edtFechaP.getText().toString());


            dbRef.child(edtNombreP.getText().toString()).setValue(prod);
            Toast.makeText(NuevoProducto.this, "Producto registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }


    });

    /*btnIngresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(edtNombreP.getText().toString()).exists()){
                        Toast.makeText(NuevoProducto.this, "Producto ya registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NuevosProd nuevosProd = new NuevosProd(edtCodigoP.getText().toString(),edtDescripcionP.getText().toString(),
                                edtPrecioP.getText().toString(), edtPrecio1P.getText().toString(), edtPrecio2P.getText().toString(),
                                edtPrecio3P.getText().toString(), edtCantidadP.getText().toString(), edtFechaP.getText().toString());
                        reference.child(edtNombreP.getText().toString()).setValue(nuevosProd);
                        Toast.makeText(NuevoProducto.this, "Producto Registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });*/
}

private void Escanear(View view) {
    vistaEscaner = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    vistaEscaner.setResultHandler(new zxingscanner ());
    setContentView(vistaEscaner);
    vistaEscaner.startCamera();
}

public class zxingscanner implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    public void handleResult (final Result result){
        String dato = result.getText();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevo_producto);
        vistaEscaner.startCamera();
        edtCodigoP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtCodigoP);
        edtCodigoP.setText(dato);

    }
}
```

}

[image: Anexo la imagen de mi base de datos]

Comment: podrias mostrar la estructura de tu base de datos?

Comment: Listo ya agregue la estructura de la base de datos y reformule la pregunta

Comment: podrias detallar un poco mejor ahora el problema ? gracias

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estoy realizando un app de registro de productos, donde pido código de barras, nombre, descripción, precio de compra, precio de venta 1 2 y 3, etc. Si lo ingreso manualmente registro correctamente en Firebase, el detalle es que cuando inicio la cámara para escanear el código de barras de cierto producto, no me deja registrar, pienso que hay algún en el momento que inicializo la clase de ZXingScanner pero no lo he encontrado, llevo días así. Concretamente cuando ingreso el código de barras manualmente se registra, cuando lo escaneo para tenerlo automáticamente hay error

Comment: entonces el problema esta cuando escaneas el codigo queres que se suba solo a firebase no ?

Comment: Si es correcto quiero que cuando escaneo el codigo se suba a firebase, no lo quiero poner manualmente

Answer (score 0):

Al trabajar en hilos diferentes prueba a inicializar los campos de nuevo dentro del handler. Puede no ser la mejor solucion pero funciona. Intenta a crear un metodo que inicialice las variables InicializarCampos()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevo_producto);

//edtCodigoP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtCodigoP);
edtNombreP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNombreP);
edtDescripcionP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtDescripcionP);
edtPrecioP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrecioP);
edtPrecio1P = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrecio1P);
edtPrecio2P = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrecio2P);
edtPrecio3P = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrecio3P);
edtCantidadP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCantidadP);
edtFechaP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtFechaP);

btnIngresar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIngresar);

btnEscanear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEscaner);
btnEscanear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Escanear(view);
    }
});

//final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
//final DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Productos");
final DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Productos");
btnIngresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        NuevosProd prod = new NuevosProd(edtCodigoP.getText().toString(),edtNombreP.getText().toString(),
                edtDescripcionP.getText().toString(), edtPrecioP.getText().toString(),edtPrecio1P.getText().toString(),
                edtPrecio2P.getText().toString(),edtPrecio3P.getText().toString(),edtCantidadP.getText().toString(),
                edtFechaP.getText().toString());


        dbRef.child(edtNombreP.getText().toString()).setValue(prod);
        Toast.makeText(NuevoProducto.this, "Producto registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }


});

/*btnIngresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(edtNombreP.getText().toString()).exists()){
                    Toast.makeText(NuevoProducto.this, "Producto ya registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    NuevosProd nuevosProd = new NuevosProd(edtCodigoP.getText().toString(),edtDescripcionP.getText().toString(),
                            edtPrecioP.getText().toString(), edtPrecio1P.getText().toString(), edtPrecio2P.getText().toString(),
                            edtPrecio3P.getText().toString(), edtCantidadP.getText().toString(), edtFechaP.getText().toString());
                    reference.child(edtNombreP.getText().toString()).setValue(nuevosProd);
                    Toast.makeText(NuevoProducto.this, "Producto Registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
});*/
}

private void Escanear(View view) {
vistaEscaner = new ZXingScannerView(this);
vistaEscaner.setResultHandler(new zxingscanner ());
setContentView(vistaEscaner);
vistaEscaner.startCamera();
}

public class zxingscanner implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
public void handleResult (final Result result){

//edtCodigoP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtCodigoP);
edtNombreP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNombreP);
edtDescripcionP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtDescripcionP);
edtPrecioP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrecioP);
edtPrecio1P = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrecio1P);
edtPrecio2P = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrecio2P);
edtPrecio3P = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrecio3P);
edtCantidadP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCantidadP);
edtFechaP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtFechaP);

btnIngresar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIngresar);

btnEscanear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEscaner);


    String dato = result.getText();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevo_producto);
    vistaEscaner.startCamera();
    edtCodigoP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtCodigoP);
    edtCodigoP.setText(dato);

}
}
}
```

O BIEN CON EL METODO:

InicializarCampos

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevo_producto);

InicializarCampos();

btnEscanear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Escanear(view);
    }
});

//final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
//final DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Productos");
final DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Productos");
btnIngresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        NuevosProd prod = new NuevosProd(edtCodigoP.getText().toString(),edtNombreP.getText().toString(),
                edtDescripcionP.getText().toString(), edtPrecioP.getText().toString(),edtPrecio1P.getText().toString(),
                edtPrecio2P.getText().toString(),edtPrecio3P.getText().toString(),edtCantidadP.getText().toString(),
                edtFechaP.getText().toString());


        dbRef.child(edtNombreP.getText().toString()).setValue(prod);
        Toast.makeText(NuevoProducto.this, "Producto registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }


});

/*btnIngresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(edtNombreP.getText().toString()).exists()){
                    Toast.makeText(NuevoProducto.this, "Producto ya registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    NuevosProd nuevosProd = new NuevosProd(edtCodigoP.getText().toString(),edtDescripcionP.getText().toString(),
                            edtPrecioP.getText().toString(), edtPrecio1P.getText().toString(), edtPrecio2P.getText().toString(),
                            edtPrecio3P.getText().toString(), edtCantidadP.getText().toString(), edtFechaP.getText().toString());
                    reference.child(edtNombreP.getText().toString()).setValue(nuevosProd);
                    Toast.makeText(NuevoProducto.this, "Producto Registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
});*/
}

private void Escanear(View view) {
vistaEscaner = new ZXingScannerView(this);
vistaEscaner.setResultHandler(new zxingscanner ());
setContentView(vistaEscaner);
vistaEscaner.startCamera();
}

public void InicializarCampos(){

//edtCodigoP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtCodigoP);
edtNombreP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNombreP);
edtDescripcionP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtDescripcionP);
edtPrecioP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrecioP);
edtPrecio1P = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrecio1P);
edtPrecio2P = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrecio2P);
edtPrecio3P = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrecio3P);
edtCantidadP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCantidadP);
edtFechaP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtFechaP);

btnIngresar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIngresar);

btnEscanear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEscaner);

}


public class zxingscanner implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
public void handleResult (final Result result){

InicializarCampos();

    String dato = result.getText();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevo_producto);
    vistaEscaner.startCamera();
    edtCodigoP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtCodigoP);
    edtCodigoP.setText(dato);

}
}
```

Comment: Me sigue marcando el mismo error :/ no puedo registrar

Comment: Pero el programa peta? o sigue funcionando pero no deja realizar la funcion ue necesitas?